# MySQL - How to count "Products Also Viewed", ordered by frequency

Tags: mysql

I am logging product views per user in a database table.

```
 product_id | user_id
 --------------------
 1          | 1
 3          | 1 
 2          | 1
 4          | 1
 ...
 1          | 2
 3          | 2
 2          | 2
 ...
 1          | 3
 3          | 3
 5          | 3
```

The aim is: For a given product, return a list of 4 products "Customers also viewed", ordered by frequency. So, for product 1, product 3 should appear first as it has been viewed with 3 the most (three) times.

I'd like to form a query that will give me this data in the following way for a given product ID:

```
 product_id | viewed_with_id | frequency_viewed_together
 -------------------------------------------------------
 1          | 3              | 3
 1          | 2              | 2
 1          | 4              | 1
 1          | 5              | 1
```

To summarise:

- All 3 users have viewed products 1 and 3 (so frequency is 3)
- Users 1 and 2 have viewed products 1 and 2 (so frequency is 2)
- Only user 1 has viewed products 1 and 4 (so frequency is 1)
- Only user 3 has viewed products 1 and 5 (so frequency is 1)

My current query is:

```
SELECT u.product_id,u.user_id, p.product_id
    FROM also_viewed u
JOIN also_viewed p ON u.user_id = p.user_id
WHERE u.product_id = 1
   AND p.product_id != 1
```

This shows the other products viewed by users who have viewed product 1, but doesn't group the products by frequency. I'll keep trying.

Here is a dump of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `also_viewed` (
`id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
`product_id` mediumint(9) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `also_viewed` (`id`, `product_id`, `user_id`, `updated_at`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, NULL),
(2, 2, 1, NULL),
(3, 3, 1, NULL),
(4, 4, 1, NULL),
(5, 1, 2, NULL),
(6, 3, 2, NULL),
(7, 2, 2, NULL),
(8, 1, 3, NULL),
(9, 3, 3, NULL),
(10, 5, 3, NULL);
```

Comment: What query have you tried and what happens when you execute it?

Comment: Edited to add current query

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/93e37d/9

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.product_id, p.product_id, COUNT(p.product_id) idx
    FROM also_viewed u
JOIN also_viewed p 
ON  p.product_id != u.product_id
WHERE u.product_id = 1
GROUP BY u.user_id, u.product_id, p.product_id
ORDER BY idx DESC
```